# Is the inputmode attribute valid (in HTML5 forms) or not?

Tags: forms, html, validation

I am getting validation errors with the inputmode attribute on text areas and text fields. The validator tells me *Attribute inputmode not allowed on element input at this point* but [the HTML5 spec indicates that it is allowed](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#input-modalities:-the-inputmode-attribute).

Is there actually something wrong with this code, or is the validator at fault?

Here is a bare bones case which will produce exactly this kind of validation error (twice), in one case on an email input, and on the other on a textarea.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="contactme.php">         
      <label class='pas block'>
        Your E-Mail:<br/>
        <input type='email' name='email' required inputmode='latin' placeholder='your e-mail here' />
      </label>
        <label class='pas block'>
                Your Message:<br/>
                <textarea name='message' required inputmode='latin' placeholder='and your message here!'></textarea>
        </label>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps the validator is not an HTML5 validator or in HTML5 mode

Comment: I tried both the w3c validator and the whatwg one.

Both validators are in html5 mode, and (i.e. because) this example has a html5 doctype

Comment: Perhaps `inputmode` cannot be combined with (some values of) `type`?

Comment: Valid yes, however it should be noted that at this time no browser (that I know of has implemented it yet) https://twitter.com/scunliffe/status/691370670018686976 - which is frustrating as it would overcome other (IMHO bugs) with `<input type="number"/>`

Comment: Tangential to the question about validity/spec, but you can see real-world support for this feature at http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-inputmode. As of today, upsettingly, it's still completely unimplemented everywhere.

Comment: I'm using `inputmode` for Chrome and `x-inputmode` for FF -- works on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML5 spec says

> The following content attributes must not be specified and do not apply to the element: accept, alt, checked, dirname, formaction, formenctype, formmethod, formnovalidate, formtarget, height, **inputmode**, max, min, src, step, and width.

It's under bookkeeping details at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#e-mail-state-(type=email)

Comment: This bookkeeping details is specifically for `[type=email]` elements, and for text and search state ([spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#text-(type=text)-state-and-search-state-(type=search))) it says *The following common input element content attributes, IDL attributes, and methods apply to the element: .....* ***inputmode***

Answer (score 9):

Also, see the chart about which attributes apply to the different input types here:
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-input-element.html#attr-input-type

The "inputmode" attribute applies only to "text" and "search".

UPDATE 2019-09-04: "inputmode" is now a global attribute (per WHATWG) and can be specified on any HTML element: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes

Another reference page for "inputmode":
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode

On another note, "inputmode" is not a W3C HTML5 attribute, but it is a W3C HTML 5.1 attribute (at least at the time I'm writing this). UPDATE 2019-09-04: "inputmode" has been removed from HTML 5.2 and HTML 5.3.

Comment: Thanks - that chart is very handy in clearing up (at least for me) what options/attrs apply to which input types.

Comment: As of 2019, it doesn't look like `inputmode` is part of the spec that you linked anymore.

Comment: @balu - looks like they removed it from the chart... also, it is now a global attribute: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes

Answer (score 1):

Five years after the question was asked, some may wonder why some of the properties listed by @dsas doesn't trigger such errors, like `enctype`
The answer is simple support, while `enctype` for instance gained a wide support
`inputmethod` is supported only as of IE11 and Edge 14, for more infos click [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=inputmethod)